# How to get the li element from next page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a card region which has pagination. This card region is basically `<li>` elmements inside unordered list. HTML codes would be like below. Because of the number of `<li>` elements, I used pagination and put them into multiple pages. Users can click the `next` button to go to next page an view. Now I want to get all the list items and save them to `pdf` , how to get the list elements from multiple pages in Javascripts? So far, the javascript codes can only print the first page.

```
<ul class="a-CardView-items a-CardView-items--grid2col LAYOUT-CLASS col-sm-12 mb-3">
    <li class="a-CardView-item col-sm-6" data-id="4" data-rownum="1">
        <div
            class="a-CardView has-title has-subtitle has-body has-secondary has-badge has-media has-media--body has-media--square has-media--cover CARD-CLASS">
            <div
                class="a-CardView-media a-CardView-media--body a-CardView-media--square a-CardView-media--cover MEDIA-CLASS">
                <img class="a-CardView-mediaImg"
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1407305/pexels-photo-1407305.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
                    alt="Photo of Fms" loading="lazy">
            </div>
            <div class="a-CardView-header">
                <div class="a-CardView-headerBody">
                    <h3 class="a-CardView-title TITLE-CLASS">Fr Ad</h3>
                    <h4 class="a-CardView-subTitle SUBTITLE-CLASS">test4@gmail.com</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="a-CardView-badge BADGE-CLASS" title="C 133">
                    <span class="a-CardView-badgeLabel">Class</span> <span class="a-CardView-badgeValue">133</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="a-CardView-body">
                <div class="a-CardView-mainContent">
                    <!--<div class="a-CardView-mainContent BODY-CLASS chip  item-status" key=4>Invited to Interview</div>-->

                    <div class="a-CardView-mainContent BODY-CLASS chip  item-status" key="4"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="a-CardView-subContent BODY-CLASS chip">New Candidates</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="a-CardView-item col-sm-6" data-id="48" data-rownum="2">
        <div
            class="a-CardView has-title has-subtitle has-body has-secondary has-badge has-media has-media--body has-media--square has-media--cover CARD-CLASS">
            <div
                class="a-CardView-media a-CardView-media--body a-CardView-media--square a-CardView-media--cover MEDIA-CLASS">
                <img class="a-CardView-mediaImg"
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1407305/pexels-photo-1407305.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
                    alt="Photo ena" loading="lazy">
            </div>
            <div class="a-CardView-header">
                <div class="a-CardView-headerBody">
                    <h3 class="a-CardView-title TITLE-CLASS">Jo Ba</h3>
                    <h4 class="a-CardView-subTitle SUBTITLE-CLASS">test3@gmail.com</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="a-CardView-badge BADGE-CLASS" title="C 133">
                    <span class="a-CardView-badgeLabel">Class</span> <span class="a-CardView-badgeValue">133</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="a-CardView-body">
                <div class="a-CardView-mainContent">
                    <!--<div class="a-CardView-mainContent BODY-CLASS chip  item-status" key=48>Invited to Interview</div>-->

                    <div class="a-CardView-mainContent BODY-CLASS chip  item-status" key="48"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="a-CardView-subContent BODY-CLASS chip">New Candidates</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("print_btn");
//var createpdf = document.getElementsByClassName('LAYOUT-CLASS');
var createpdf = document.getElementById('export_candidates_Cards');
//var createpdf = document.querySelectorAll('.a-CardView-item ');
//var number_of_card = document.getElementById('test').getAttribute('pageLength');
console.log(createpdf);
var opt = {
         margin: 0,
         filename: 'Candiates.pdf',
         html2canvas: { 
            scale: 2
         },
         jsPDF: {
            unit: 'in',
            format: 'A4',
            orientation: 'portrait'   
         },
         pagebreak: { mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy'] }
};

html2pdf().set(opt).from(createpdf).save();
```

Comment: what does `I used pagination and put them into multiple pages` mean? what element is `document.getElementById('export_candidates_Cards')`? Are you using CSS to show/hide the "pages"? i.e. do the pages exist in the DOM, but only one is visible?

Comment: @JaromandaX It's a card region. The card region has paginations. Each page has 12 cards and there are 7 pages of them. I'm not using CSS to show/hide. I just wanted iterate all the li elements and print the cards to one single pdf files.